# Trying to iterate through a hash, extract unique keys and add the values

Tags: ruby, loops, hash, iterator, aggregate-functions

I have a `Mysql2::Result` that has a bunch of rows in it. The results are formatted in a hash as such:

```
{"thing_name" => "email",   "count(*)" => 1000}
{"thing_name" => "email",   "count(*)" => 800}
{"thing_name" => "ads",     "count(*)" => 500}
{"thing_name" => "display", "count(*)" => 700}
```

My goal is to iterate through all of these and create a new hash that has one of each key and the sum of their counts as the value associated with that key.

I can successfully iterate through and put the "thing_name"s in an array and run `.uniq` on them to collapse duplicates into one entry but I can't figure out how to associate the values and do the appropriate math on them. Or how to do this as a hash.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
thing_type = results.collect {|row| row["thing_name"]}
thing_type = thing_type.uniq
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 # Provide a default value of zero for unknown keys
 counts = Hash.new { |hash,key| hash[key] = 0 }

 result.each do |row|
     counts[ row["thing_name"] ] += row["count(*)"]
 end
```

When you pass a block to `Hash.new`, it will use that block whenever you first try to get an unknown key (for example, by going `counts[...] += ...` on a key that doesn't exist). Ruby will call your block and pass in as the arguments the existing hash object, and the key that you are trying to set.

Comment: Thanks so much @robbrit! Can you explain the hash[key] section of the iterator in a little more detail please? I'm a bit confused there.

Comment: There, hopefully that helps a bit!

Comment: beat me to it. I would use Hash.new(0) instead. Currently every time the key is not found it will call the block. Using the Hash.new(0) it will just return 0.

Comment: @KassymDorsel: Yeah that works perfectly well in this situation, however I like to be in the habit of passing a block since sometimes there is quirky behaviour when setting the default to a mutable object like an array or another hash.